# In RuboCop, what's the difference between error and fatal severities?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

What's the difference between the severities "error" and "fatal" in RuboCop?

The documentation about [severity](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#severity) says

> Each cop has a default severity level based on which department it
>   belongs to. The level is warning for Lint and convention for all the
>   others. Cops can customize their severity level. Allowed params are
>   refactor, convention, warning, error and fatal.
>
> There is one exception from the general rule above and that is
>   Lint/Syntax, a special cop that checks for syntax errors before the
>   other cops are invoked. It can not be disabled and its severity
>   (fatal) can not be changed in configuration.

Which suggests fatal is more severe than error, but I can write code that is not valid ruby and it only generates an "error" level offense.

```
def foo
  42
# No end

$ rubocop -D invalid.rb 
Inspecting 1 file
E

Offenses:

invalid.rb:3:11: E: unexpected token $end
# No end


1 file inspected, 1 offense detected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rubocop source suggests that encoding problems are the only ones that can lead to a fatal outcome. If you search for "fatal" on the rubocop github, you see very few mentions, and if you track where it is called, that's basically it.